# different label for each additional added form

Tags: jquery, html

I am `adding addition form` on `button click.`

I want to have `different label for each added form.`

I am doing it in the following way and the problem is label changes for every 
form. How i can solve it.

Any idea?

**html**

```
<div id="jointBuyer" class="JointBuyerDive" style="display:none">
    <div id="jBuyer">
        <div id="inner"class="col-lg-6">
            <form id="buyerForm" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Buyer</label>
            -----------
            -----------
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 0;
    $("#testButton").click(function() {
      $("#jBuyer").clone().appendTo("#jointBuyer"); 
      $('.changeBuyer').text('Buyer ' + index); 
      index++; 
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your code does not work as posted. Here is a working version changing the text on the last label and not duplicating any IDs and actually showing the cloned form too

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 0;
  $("#testButton").click(function() {
    $("#jBuyer").clone().appendTo("#jointBuyer").attr("id","jBuyer"+index).show();
    $('.changeBuyer').last().text('Buyer ' + index);
    index++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="testButton">Add</button>
<div id="jointBuyer" class="JointBuyerDive"><div>
<div id="jBuyer" style="display:none">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label class="changeBuyer">Buyer</label>
      ----------- -----------
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, let me check,

Answer (score 3):

---

You should only change the text for newly added form. Therefore you can use :last to target the latest added form.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 0;
    $("#testButton").click(function() {
      $("#jBuyer").clone().appendTo("#jointBuyer"); 
      $('.changeBuyer:last').text('Buyer ' + index); 
      index++; 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change text of the cloned form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 0;
    $("#testButton").click(function() {
      var clonedForm = $("#jBuyer").clone();
      clonedForm.text('Buyer ' + index); 
      clonedForm.appendTo("#jointBuyer"); 
      index++; 
    });
});
```